# Rijndeal algorithm decrypt data missing some character in c#

Tags: c#, rijndael

I am using a Rijndeal algorithm to encrypt and decrypt a string value. This method works fine in most of the cases, but in same cases on one machine I'm missing characters after decryption.

Here is my sample code

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    try
    {                   


        string incoming = cipherText.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
        switch (cipherText.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: incoming += "=="; break;
            case 3: incoming += "="; break;
        }
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(incoming);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                  

          return "Exception";
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to post your encrypt method as well. Can it be related to  custom encoding (Your string replace thingy?)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - ideally with the encryption side as well as description. Note that aside from anything else, you're assuming that a single call to `Stream.Read` will do what you want, which isn't a good idea. (It would be better to create a `StreamReader` wrapping `cryptoStream` and then call `ReadToEnd`.) Also note that you should use `using` statements to dispose of your streams - and catching exceptions and effectively ignoring them is a *really* bad idea in almost all cases.

Comment: Hi @sumo, are you missing 'a character' (one) or 'some characters'? At the start, the end or somewhere in the middle?